# long polling mocking using express

Tags: javascript, rest, express

My frontend need this data to display a list - name and score.

```
[{id: 1, name: 'james', score: null}, {id: 2, name: 'john', score: null}]
```

frontend will call every second because score value will come in much later, assuming backend is doing computation.

so frontend will call the endpoint every second till all the scores is returned.

Below is the steps how frontend should get the data from the backend.

1. fire first call

> [{id: 1, name: 'james', score: null}, {id: 2, name: 'john', score:
>   null}]

2. render the names
3. display loading for prices
4. fire second call

> [{id: 1, name: 'james', score: 1.2}, {id: 2, name: 'john', score:
>   2.2}]

5. done, loading dismissed

How do I mock an endpoint in express so that I can get this result in the frontend? my problem is express endpoint aka function is non persistent, it's hard to fake at which call the score will be returned.

Comment: You can answer a http request after a few seconds, so there is no need for polling.

Comment: @JonasWilms I have to make http call every seconds, to get the names rendered, then keep calling till I got the scores. Did I misunderstood polling?

Comment: No, but it makes little sense here.

Answer (score -1):

You could start a timer if no timer was set yet, that somewhen fills out the scores:

```
 const data = [/*...*/];

 let loading;
 function load() {
   for(const el of data)
     el.score = Math.random();
 }

 app.get("/api/", (req, res) => {
   if(!loading) loading = setTimeout(load, 5000);

   res.json({ data });
 });
```

Comment: good idea but timeout work for 2 steps, what if at the frontend has a load progress indicator? Then the server have to mock more than 2 steps.

Comment: multiple timers maybe?

Comment: yea but how can you make sure the first call can return the name to the frontend?

Comment: I don't get you.

Comment: the first call, the api have to return score as null, then only the score send some value to the backend, settimeout as I know delay the sending of score but how you ensure the first time the score is null?

Comment: this won't work, tried it, because when the endpoint is hit, js execute from top to bottom, setTimeout doesn't have any effect here, I think I need persistent data.